# Gridview event not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a requirement where i have to update a textbox if any of the value in my grid view changes.. I have a gridview with 2 rows ..

one a template field with label and another template field with a textbox...

my Grid view looks like

```
                   name                 value
                   a                     (empty textbox)
                   b                     (empty textbox)
                   c                      (empty textbox)
```

now when the user enters a value in teh text box it should automatically update another textbox which is linked to this.

Here my questions is when someone enters a value in the textbox an event should be fired!

(I am getting the names a,b,c, from database). i dont want to have an edit link or update link because all the values to be entered are mandatory!

i tried Grid_SelectedIndexChanged1 but this not firing.. is there something i am missing or i need to change so that the evant is fired and i can update the other textbox??

I am new to ASP.NET so please help!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: TextBox has an AutoPostback property set it to true and handle the TextChanged event or do it on clientside with javascript.

Comment: Would please tell me what you mean by linking textboxes ?

Comment: i tried that too.. but how to i know which rows textbox changed?

Comment: @ persian dev i have other textbox which needs to update the values i get from these feilds.. i have a text to edit with the values provided from these textbox fields!

Comment: selectedindexchanged fires when the index of the selected row changes, which hasn't occurred in this instance.

if all you are doing is updating another UI element with the same text, then making a trip the server is overkill. javascript, more specifically jquery will be a much better solution.

Comment: the text which i have to update with these values are also from the database.. so i need to anyways go back to the server! is there any way i can handle my issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the Current Row Index like below...

```
((GridViewRow)((TextBox)sender).NamingContainer).RowIndex
```

Create a handler for `OnTextChanged` event and set the `AutoPostBack Property True`.

```
protected void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     int CurrentGridIndex = ((GridViewRow)((TextBox)sender).NamingContainer).RowIndex
}
```

Comment: @pankaj... i tried doing it when i do that and trying to access the cell its returning an empty string!

Comment: i did some thing like GridViewRow gv = Grid.Rows[CurrentGridIndex];
        string value = gv.Cells[0].Text;

Comment: You can find the controls inside your cells like `(ControlType)gv.FindControl("YourID")`

Answer (score 2):

If the updates are supposed to be triggered when the text changes, you should use the `OnTextChanged` event of the `TextBox`, and set `AutoPostBack` to true.

**EDIT**

To avoid duplicating efforts here, using the above approach you can find the row index using the technique that **Pankaj Garg** outlined in his answer:

```
int rowIndex = ((GridViewRow)((TextBox)sender).NamingContainer).RowIndex;
```

The biggest caveat to this approach is that it's not forgiving of changes in the markup. If you were to wrap the `TextBox` in another control that implements `INamingContainer`, the example above would break. For example:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server"> <!-- becomes the naming container -->
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" onchange='valueChanged(<%# Container.ItemIndex %>);' />
    </asp:Panel>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

That being said, you would want to notate your markup accordingly so other developers know to be careful when making changes.

**EDIT**

As an alternative, you could also trigger the postback in JavaScript using the `onchange` event of the `TextBox`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    valueChanged = function(rowIndex){
        __doPostBack("<%= GridView1.ClientID %>", rowIndex);
    }
</script>
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID" ...>
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" onchange='valueChanged(<%# Container.ItemIndex %>);' />
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

In the code-behind, override the `RaisePostBackEvent` method, and put your update logic there:

```
protected override void RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler source, string eventArgument)
{
    base.RaisePostBackEvent(source, eventArgument);

    if (source == GridView1)
    {
        int rowIndex = int.Parse(eventArgument);

        TextBox txt = GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl("TextBox1") as TextBox;
        if (txt != null)
        {
            var id = (int)GridView1.DataKeys[rowIndex]["ID"];
            var text = txt.Text.Trim();

            //update the database
        } 
    }    
}
```

Comment: If the GridView is in an UpdatePanel (just guessing) he will also need to add a trigger for the GridView's RowCommand.

Comment: @ thanks for the reply, the issue is i have know which value of the textbox i have now.. for example i have to know..the value of a= the value entered!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Are you saying that you need to know which row the `TextBox` corresponds to?

Comment: Hi @James - **If you were to wrap the TextBox in another control that implements INamingContainer, the example above would break.** Can you please make it more precise. Sorry did not get this sentence.

Comment: If for some reason he put the `TextBox` in a `Panel` or another control that implements `INamingContainer`, the code would break.